# MySQL Connector : could not process parameters can't delete rows

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I can't use execute method

```
conn = connect(**cinfo)
cursor = conn.cursor()
# Drop the tables.
drop_query = 'DELETE FROM %s;'
tables = ['History', 'Product', 'Category']
for table in tables:
    cursor.execute(drop_query, (table,))
conn.commit()
```

I have this error:

> Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters

**EDIT:**
I want to delete all the rows of these tables

Comment: provide a condition, otherwise how we filter what to delete?

Comment: in the official documentation it is mentioned that the condition is not mandatory if we want to delete all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `TRUNCATE`. It will remove all the rows in your given table. This is what [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html) mention about it.

> `TRUNCATE TABLE` empties a table completely. It requires the `DROP` privilege. Logically, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is similar to a `DELETE` statement that deletes all rows, or a sequence of `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements.

```py
conn = connect(**cinfo)
cursor = conn.cursor()
# Drop the tables.
drop_query = "TRUNCATE TABLE {};"
tables = ['History', 'Product', 'Category']
for table in tables:
    cursor.execute(drop_query.format(table))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

For more information you can read this [How to Delete All Rows of a MySQL Table in Python](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-delete-all-rows-of-a-MySQL-table-in-Python.php) article too. Use string concatenate with `format`.

```py
conn = connect(**cinfo)
cursor = conn.cursor()
# Drop the tables.
drop_query = "DELETE FROM {};"
tables = ['History', 'Product', 'Category']
for table in tables:
    cursor.execute(drop_query.format(table))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: that's what i have "1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''History'' at line 1",

Comment: but when i do: 
`cursor.execute('DELETE FROM History;')
 cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Product;')
 cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Category;')
 conn.commit()`
it's work..

Comment: I updated your code line with using `format`. Please check it and let me know @r_lnup7

Comment: okay @r_lnup7, just surround it with double quotes. `'DELETE FROM %s;'` change in this way --> `"DELETE FROM %s;"`. This will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Ok the problem was the '%s' !
Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome and I also learn new thing from this question thanks to you @r_lnup7.